# Should the font-size and fontsize tags be merged/clarified?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I'm asking since I was just trying to tag my own question and couldn't figure out which one I should be using. Is one supposed to be the CSS attribute and the other a more general tag? It's unclear to me. [font-size](/questions/tagged/font-size) has 209 questions, and [fontsize](/questions/tagged/fontsize) has 301.

Comment: No, they're the same. It seems that a lot of people are hypen-averse when it comes to tags. There are a *lot* of duplicates created this way, and there should probably be a better way of handling them than manual merges each time.

Answer (score 2):

The tags should be merged as they are really referring to the same thing. I prefer [font-size](/questions/tagged/font-size), but I don't find any difference between using one or the other.

Nowadays, it would not be possible to create [font-size](/questions/tagged/font-size), when there is already [fontsize](/questions/tagged/fontsize). For example, if you try to create [an-droid](/questions/tagged/an-droid), you get the following dialog when you click on the "Save Edits" button.

[image: screenshot]